# How do I keep CONSTANT WATTAGE power on indoor bikes?

Tags: cardio, gym, bicycling, zone

I have started with Zone 2 training, where it is important to keep constant wattage

How would I do this on the equipment which supports this the best?  Should it correct me by varying resistance  or should it give me ques to correct, or both?

If constant wattage is not supported, is it something else I can use?
(Like rpm, HR, calories)

Zone 2 takes a lot of time, so it is important that maintaining constant wattage does not take a lot of attention.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking--if the bike supports auto-adjustments, use it. HR can fluctuate, but many bikes support constant HR so it still might be the best bet. Calories is generally meaningless, although if it's used as a reference, maybe, with the caveat that it's almost always an aggregate of other data already. RPM can vary if load varies, so it'd depend on bike settings, but might work once you find a static setting combo that lines up with expected power output, but auto-adjusting to maintain RPM would change the power output.

Comment: What is "auto-adjustments" usually called?  What can usually be kept constant?

Comment: Completely dependent on the equipment.

Comment: In Zone 2 is the maximum sustainable wattage - this means you HR should not drift upwards.  You could also fix HR and look at wattage.  In the beginning you start with a calculated HR anyway.